# How to design rounded boxes and separators (like the App Settings view)?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am wondering what is the good way to design interfaces such as the one in the Settings view on an application, for instance :

What I want to do is the nice round rectangle to separate categories and horizontal line separators between categories, I can have a label, text field, slider or any other control in each line...

Do we need to use an image in the background, that seems quite dirty to me, and I cant find any control in IB that seem to do the same kind of layout.

So, how is this done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `UITableView` and set it's style to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`. Remember that the standard `UITableViewCell`'s will just let you show some text and you may need to create custom `UITableViewCell`'s to achieve more (for example, a on-off switch).

If you wan't to customise it you can add a background image. To do this, place a `UIImageView` behind the `UITableView` and make sure you set the `UITableView` background colour to clear:

```
theTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

To seperate the categories make use of the "sections".

Comment: can we do this all in IB or do we have to use xcode to position the different controls we want to have on each cell?

Comment: Yes, you can. Use the Inspector to change values of the objects in IB. However you need to populate your UITableView in code.

Comment: thanks, i never saw that option... now i'll also try this tutorial that should help : http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can use grouped table.You can have sections with different/same number of rows.